# Expand variables in a batch script like parameter extension

Tags: batch-file

I know that if I have a batch script with parameters, I can expand those parameters to fully qualified paths like so

```
set expanded=%~f1
```

How can I do the same thing with a variable in a for loop? I'm looping over the lines in a text file and I want to expand each line (which contains a relative path) to a full path. The following is not allowed

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "paths.txt"') do (
    set p=%%f
    set p=!p:abc=def! # modify p a bit
    set expanded=!~fp!  <--- invalid
)
endlocal
```

Can this be done?

Comment: what's the problem with `set "p=%%~ff"`?

Comment: That's one reason why I usually use uppercase for variables and lower case  modifiers `%%~fF`. Just to **me** not getting confused 

Comment: If your text file does not hold full paths, _you said they were relative_, then it can only add the missing part if the relative path is also relative to the script/current directory. You cannot expect it to know a missing section of a text string!

Comment: @npocmaka I should have expanded my example. I actually modify `p` a bit (e.g chop off the first few characters) before I want to do this expansion

Comment: @JordanCrittenden - then show the full example. I suppose you'll have to use nested for loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is possible, and you don't need to set a variable p. Consider this:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "paths.txt"') do (
    set p=%%f
    set expanded=!~fp!  <--- invalid
    set valid_expanded=%%~ff <--- valid
)
endlocal
```

If you still want to set the variable p, however:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /F "tokens=*" %%f in ('type "paths.txt"') do (
    set p=%%~ff
)
endlocal
```

It basically works the same as it would when calling labels and files.

Comment: The fundamental question asked has not been answered. You answered for a narrow context. The question title asks: Given a variable %path%, is there a way to do ~f expansion? Can you please expound on your answer so that those of us who find this result have a complete answer?